# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am a bit of a freshman in rails, so please bear with me.
I get a routing error on my tests. The tests are as follwoing:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "ProducerPages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    @producer = Producer.create(name:"Example Producer", 
                             email: "producer@example.com", password: "foobar",
                             password_confirmation: "foobar")
    before { visit producer_path(@producer) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: producer.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: producer.name) }
  end
end
```

and the failure produced is:

```
Failures:

  1) ProducerPages profile page
     Failure/Error: before { visit producer_path(@producer) }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"producers", :id=>nil}
     # ./spec/requests/producer_pages_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It looks, I do something wrong with creating the producer instance variable. I tried to make that a normal variable, but then I get this error:

```
  1) ProducerPages profile page
     Failure/Error: before { visit producer_path(producer) }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"producers", 
     :id=>#<Producer id: nil, name: "Example Producer", 
     email: "producer@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, 
     password_digest: "$2a$04$pXAEklj4nzYe48ojR5Ps/Oh8Ea9.QqKOajYBD2Rv0mQ9...", 
     remember_token: nil, admin: false, oid: nil, contact_name: nil, 
     street: nil, postal_code: nil, city: nil, country: nil, url: nil, 
     telephone: nil, cellular: nil, type: "Producer", producer_id: nil, 
     client_key: nil, product_count: 0>}
     # ./spec/requests/producer_pages_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

the routes.rb file contains

```
  resources :producers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your @producer object is nil, may be it throws an exception.

Comment: ok. half way. I made the create call inside the before block. Now it isn't nil, but throws the error as the call to the (non-instance) variable. Doesn't rail maybe notice the type is Producer? This is a Single table inheritance setup.

Comment: why is id nil in the record. Create should have saved it to the database and give it an id? right?

Comment: add a bang `create!` so that it raises an exception when it fails validation.  but a better approach is to use mocks so you dont create db records

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Email was not unique. I wanted to use FactoryGirl but fell flat on the inheritance issue... I'll try again.